# How to upload and resize via stream?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, upload, stream, sharp

I have problems with uploading resized image to amazon s3 via `sharp` and `readStream`. It's upload only first chunk of image. But when I create a writeStream and save file localy, all ok.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const readableStream = fs.createReadStream(pathToUserFile);
  const transformer = sharp().resize(300, 250);

  readableStream.pipe(transformer);

  const params = {
    Bucket: S3_BUCKET_NAME,
    Body: readableStream, 
    ACL: 'public-read',
    Key: `S3_BUCKET_PATH/${name}`,
    ContentType: type
  }

  s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) reject(err);
    if (data) resolve();
  })
});
```

Maybe I do something wrong? I can save resized file to disk and send it... But I want send file without local saving